# Select not rendered in material design - Unexpected token `<`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, materialize

I am getting results in my Ajax call but the populated `select` element is not rendered in material style, only in the select browser-default. I have already tried various forms of render my function in `$('select').material_select();` both inside in `$.each`, `$.append` and on success function but with no results.

Template side.

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
   <select id="getUnit" ></select>
   <label>Units</label>
  </div>
```

Ajax Jquery Get.

```
$(function () {
  //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/product/unit-measurement-search',
    success: function (unitMeasurement) {
      //get a reference to the select element
      $unit = $('#getUnit');
      //clear the current content of the select
      $unit.html('');
      //iterate over the data and append a select option
      $.each(unitMeasurement, function (info, unitSearch) {
        $unit.append('<option id="' + unitSearch.descriptionUnitMeasurement + '">' + unitSearch.descriptionUnitMeasurement + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Back end process request json.

```
router.get('/product/unit-measurement-search', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT 
   acronymUnitMeasurement,descriptionUnitMeasurement FROM unit_measurement',
   function (err, unitMeasurement, fields) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }
     res.send(unitMeasurement);
   }
  );
});
```

Return in front-end template only displays label of select.

Edit:

This is my console output:

[image]

Comment: Where are you selecting the select? Is it $unit?

Comment: After the `$.each` finishes, do `$unit.material_select();`. That should do it.

Comment: @epascarello yesss

Comment: @trincot not loading :c check this my console bug https://i.imgur.com/JXLU0Oy.png

Comment: From the image it looks like you did not include Materialize correctly. Can you include the HTML where you included jQuery and Materialize?

Comment: @trincot check this print of my head html https://imgur.com/a/IhrL1

Comment: Please check the actual content of `js/materialize.min.js`: it looks like it is corrupted. The first character should *not* be a `<` in that file.

Comment: @trincot what would you recommend? remove type of script, just let `js/materialize.min.js` instead `js/materialize.js` or move all these materialize js lib in head of template instead of below body?

Comment: Ì would first replace the `src` attribute value with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js` and see if the error persists. If not, download that file again, don't open it, but copy it in your `js` folder, ...etc.

Comment: @trincot oh men you save my time xD big thankssss i marked the answer as answered

Comment: I have added it as a proper answer. Please mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console showed this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `<`                       materialize.js:1

...and the same error for the other `modal.js` script you load.

This suggests that the script file is corrupted. It could be it was saved incorrectly. Maybe when you downloaded it, you opened it in the browser as a web page, and saved that page in HTML encoding to the final location. Or still something else happened.

To verify that it works with a proper script file, replace your script tag from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js">
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/j‌​s/materialize.min.js">
```

Now you should no longer get that error in the console. You can then proceed to properly download that file (don't open it), copy it to the `js` folder, and put your `src` attribute back to what it was.

Once the console errors are solved, you still need to make the `select` element render properly. After the `$.each` loop finishes, do `$unit.material_select();`. That should make the element render as desired.